# Importing modules in Python (numpy, scipy, etc)

Tags: python, numpy, python-idle

I have a problem importing modules (numpy, scipy, sympy to be precise) through the IDLE shell. I have run the following statement **print(sys.prefix)** in both Mac OS shell and IDLE shell and (thankfully) I get the following two different results:

Mac OS Shell: *'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7'*

IDLE shell: *'/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4'*

Consequently, I tried to **sys.path.append** the 2.7 path in the IDLE shell and I re-run the import statement again but to no avail. At this stage, I am not sure what I am doing wrong. My IDLE shell uses Python version 3.4.1.

Thank you in advance for any help or suggestions. It will be much appreciated.

Comment: You want to append it to the Python site packages. That's where the imports should be stored.

Comment: Hi. I haven't tried that before. Would you mind explaining how do I go about doing it?

Comment: Yeah, sorry for late response. /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ Here you can append the framework manually into the Python folder. I strongly recommend PIP or some sort of other software for downloading such extensions though. They make it easy.